# Cannot connect to hub class

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I have the following script include:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have a hub class like so:

```
public class Dashboard : Hub, IDisconnect, IConnected
{
}
```

I am trying to connect to it on client side like this:

```
$(function () {
    $.connection.Dashboard.start(function () { 

    });
});
```

but I am getting a javscript error:

```
TypeError: $.connection.Dashboard is undefined
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

@pollirrata is correct, the default naming rules will init-lower case the name of your Hub on the client side to match typical JavaScript conventions. That said, if you want to control the exact name of your hub explicitly you can apply [the `HubNameAttribute`](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubnames) like so:

```
[HubName("Dashboard")]
public class Dashboard : Hub, IDisconnect, IConnected 
{
}
```

Comment: Now I understant what is that attribute for :)

Answer (score 1):

The name of your hub is treated as lowercase on the javascript code. Have a look on the [wiki sample](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs)

So in your case you should be using `dashboard` instead of `Dashboard`